# How to get ActionBarDrawerToggle object inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

In my main activity ActionBarDrawerToggle object is present. I have to disable navigation drawer for a specific fragment (eg. fragmentB) which is called by another fragment (eg.fragmentA),where fragmentA has been inflated by the MainActivity. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Add this method to your main activity and call it when you switch the fragments to enable/disable the navigation drawer

```
public void enableNavigationDrawer(boolean isEnabled) {
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(isEnabled);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(isEnabled);
    if(isEnabled){
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1:

```
interface DrawerLocker{
    public void setDrawerLocked(boolean shouldLock);
}
```

use this in ur main activity ,paste this code in above ur class.

step 2 :

go to ur fragment where u want to hide the navigation drawer, into `onCreateView()` methode paste this code

```
  ((DrawerLocker)getActivity()).setDrawerLocked(true);
```

step 3: create onDestroyView() method as below :

```
   @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        ((DrawerLocker)getActivity()).setDrawerLocked(false);
    }
```

now run ur code and see:-) ,credit goes to another member ...i didt remember his name ...his answer helps me to solve this problem